# Reverse Engineering a legacy QlikView system - browser or desktop app?

Tags: qlikview

I've been tasked with reverse engineering a Qlikview system to migrate to another BI platform. So far I can see dashboards through a browser, but can't change them at all. Having googled I can see there's a QlikView desktop app. Question, do I need the desktop app to see/adminster the data that's behind the dashboard or can I do that through a browser?

In short is my problem getting the QlikView application downloaded and configured, or one of permissions through my browser login.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the qvw file and QV desktop to open it. There is no other way to view/edit the data or the dashboard. If you want to edit the data (change it or reload the app to bring new data) you'll need access to the underlying data as well (databases, xls or csv files etc.).

P.S. The qvw might be protected with [Section Access](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/November2022/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/Security/manage-security-with-section-access.htm) but if you can open it in the browser it might not be an issue.